# Updating text in ViewController using Save function

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ibaction

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement the save function to update text in a View Controller. I've been working from the Wenderlich tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/160519/storyboards-tutorial-ios-10-getting-started-part-2 but that is for a TableViewController and uses .append to add saved items to an array, which I can't use since I'm using a simple View Controller. I want a string that's saved in a TableViewController to be displayed in the View Controller. This is what I have so far (the saveGoal function is at the bottom). What do I need to add to my save function (or elsewhere)? I'm new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import UIKit

class LoLGoalViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}

extension LoLGoalViewController {

    @IBAction func cancelToLoLGoalViewController(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

    @IBAction func saveGoal(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

        guard let addGoalsTableViewController = segue.source as? AddGoalsTableViewController,
            let goal = addGoalsTableViewController.goal else {
                return
        }

    }
}
```

This is what the addGoalViewController looks like. I want the string goalText to show up in the View Controller where it says "Lorem ipsum dolor goal".

[image: addGoalViewController]

This is the code for the addGoalsTableViewController where goalText is input by the user:

```
import UIKit

class AddGoalsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var goal:Goal?

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SaveGoal" {
            let pointsNeededInt = Int(pointsNeededText.text!)
            let pointsEarnedInt = Int(goalProgressText.text!)
            goal = Goal(goalText: nameOfRewardText.text!, pointsToCompleteGoal: pointsNeededInt!, pointsEarnedTowardsGoal: pointsEarnedInt!)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var goalTableTitleText : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var goalProgressText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameOfRewardText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pointsNeededText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var repeatSwitch: UISwitch!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

This is the code for struct Goal:

```
import UIKit

struct Goal {
    var goalText: String
    var pointsToCompleteGoal: Int
    var pointsEarnedTowardsGoal: Int
    var repeatGoal: Bool

    init(goalText: String, pointsToCompleteGoal: Int, pointsEarnedTowardsGoal: Int, repeatGoal: Bool = false) {
        self.goalText = goalText
        self.pointsToCompleteGoal = pointsToCompleteGoal
        self.pointsEarnedTowardsGoal = pointsEarnedTowardsGoal
        self.repeatGoal = repeatGoal
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s better to do that using a delegate instead of segue

Comment: It is kind of unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Xcoder Basically, I have a TableViewController where the user types in a goal. Then there is a save function that segues to a ViewController where I want the text of that goal to be displayed. I posted the code showing where I’m at with that and I’m asking for help getting the rest of the way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your save function, use a protocol with a delegate, as @zombie has suggested.

**1** Create a public protocol:

```
protocol GoalDelegate: class {
    func passGoal(_ goal: Goal?)
}
```

**2** Create a delegate in AddGoalsTableViewController:

```
var delegate: GoalDelegate?
```

**3** When segueing to LolGoalViewController, in the prepareForSegue method, set the delegate to be the destination, and call the protocol function:

```
if let secondViewController = segue.destination as? LoLGoalViewController {
    delegate = secondViewController
    delegate?.passGoal(goal)
}
```

**4** In LoLGoalViewController, conform to the protocol:

```
class LoLGoalViewController: UIViewController, GoalDelegate {
```

Implement the method:

```
func passGoal(_ goal: Goal?) {
    //do whatever you need with the goal
}
```

Comment: Thank you Xcoder! I really appreciate your thorough answer!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)

Comment: This is awful. Why use a delegate and a protocol when you already have a reference to the destination view controller?