# Difficulty with IBOutlets in Protocol/Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller, iboutlet

I'm having difficulty with IBOutlets. I'm trying to allow the user to input a goal (called nameOfRewardText) in a table view controller (LoLAddGoalsTableViewController) and then when they click "Done", have that goal show up in a label called "currentGoalTextField" in a different view controller (LoLGoalViewController). I had been trying to implement this using a Save segue, but was advised to use a protocol with a delegate instead ([Updating text in ViewController using Save function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476429/updating-text-in-viewcontroller-using-save-function)). Now that I've replaced the Save segue with the protocol and delegate, the inputted "nameOfRewardText" text is not showing up in the "currentGoalTextField" label, I suspect because the IBOutlets are no longer tied together properly. I've attached the code and screenshots of the Outlets below to try to clarify where I'm at. Does anyone know how I could fix the IBOutlets or if there's something else I need to add to get this working? I deleted the line where I assign nameOfRewardText.text to be goal.goalText, so I think nameOfRewardText isn't getting assigned to var goal? Maybe I'm using too many names for this text (nameOfRewardText, goalText, and currentGoalTextField) and that's complicating things? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, as I'm very new to this! Thank you everybody!

Here is the struct goal:

```
import UIKit

struct Goal {
    var goalText: String
    var pointsToCompleteGoal: Int
    var pointsEarnedTowardsGoal: Int
    var repeatGoal: Bool

    init(goalText: String, pointsToCompleteGoal: Int, pointsEarnedTowardsGoal: Int, repeatGoal: Bool = false) { //Made String non-optional. If issue later, can revert.
        self.goalText = goalText
        self.pointsToCompleteGoal = pointsToCompleteGoal
        self.pointsEarnedTowardsGoal = pointsEarnedTowardsGoal
        self.repeatGoal = repeatGoal
    }
}
```

Here is the public protocol:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol GoalDelegate: class {
    func passGoal(_ goal: Goal?)
}
```

Here is where the delegate is created, and as you can see, the statement where I assign nameOfRewardText.text to be goal.goalText is now gone:

```
import UIKit

class AddGoalsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var goal:Goal?
    var delegate: GoalDelegate?

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
// HASHED OUT THE BELOW BECAUSE REPLACING WITH DELEGATE:
//        if segue.identifier == "SaveGoal" {
//            let pointsNeededInt = Int(pointsNeededText.text!)
//            let pointsEarnedInt = Int(goalProgressText.text!)
//            goal = Goal(goalText: nameOfRewardText.text!, pointsToCompleteGoal: pointsNeededInt!, pointsEarnedTowardsGoal: pointsEarnedInt!)
//        }

        if let secondViewController = segue.destination as? LoLGoalViewController{
            delegate = secondViewController
            delegate?.passGoal(goal)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var goalTableTitleText : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var goalProgressText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameOfRewardText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pointsNeededText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var repeatSwitch: UISwitch!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Screen cap of AddGoalsTableViewController with Outlets:
[image: LoLGoalViewController]

Here I conform to the protocol and call the function passGoal:

```
import UIKit

class LoLGoalViewController: UIViewController, GoalDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var currentGoalTextField: UILabel!

    func passGoal(_ goal: Goal?) {
        currentGoalTextField.text = goal?.goalText
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

extension LoLGoalViewController {

    @IBAction func cancelToLoLGoalViewController(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }
}
```

Screen cap of LoLGoalViewController with Outlets:
[image: LoLGoalViewController]

Comment: Let me know if my answer works for you.

Comment: I don’t know. I’m confused about the best way to approach this now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `LoLGoalViewController` view controller might not have fully loaded with all of its outlets. Adding on to my answer to your previous question, you can declare another variable in `LolGoalViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var currentGoalTextField: UILabel!

var goalText: String = ""
```

In your `passGoal` method, set your string to the `goalText` variable instead of the label's text:

```
func passGoal(_ goal: Goal?) {
    goalText = goal?.goalText
}
```

Lastly, in your `viewDidLoad` of `LolGoalViewController`, set the label text to be `goalText`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    currentGoalTextField.text = goalText
}
```

Comment: Why persist with the unnecessary function/"delegate"?  This code won't compile since `goalText` is not an optional.

Comment: @Paulw11 Oops, sorry for the compiling. I just copied the OP's code and edited a bit.

Comment: @Paulw11 Which `goalText` are you talking about?

Comment: Your property isn't an optional, but `goal?.goalText` will return an optional, so you will get a compile-time error.

Comment: @Paulw11 So, changing the `?` to a `!` should fix the problem?

Comment: Using ! is rarely the right fix.  You could declare the `goalText` property to be an optional, but really, why would the parameter to `passGoal` be an optional in the first place?  And why do you need `passGoal`? Just assign the property in `prepareForSegue`